# Submit a Form without Clicking Submit

Tags: javascript

I need my form to automatically hit "select" after the user has a few seconds to verify the data that is presented. The easiest way I can think to do this would be have Javascript select the submit option after a matter of seconds however most of the replies I've seen using JavaScript are just refreshing the page... is it possible to have Javascript actually select the "submit" button after a number of seconds? Here is my code:

```
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr>
    <p class="full-width">
        <span class="buttons pull-left">
            <input type="button" name="cancel" class="close"  value="<?php
            echo __('Cancel'); ?>">
        </span>
        <span class="buttons pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('Continue'); ?>">
        </span>
     </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible but why would you do that? that is a terrible user experience. What if the user is not done verifying the data? just have the user click submit when they are ready to do so. Keep it simple.

Comment: It's a verification step after the user has already selected but the user has time to verify the name (which is the only thing being verified) when they select it. It's all internal, and much more efficient with the application we are using it in. The only piece of data is the the name, which is verified when the user selects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do a submit after a set time interval using `setTimeout`

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a37240dz/